# Can't enter unicode character with Alt+ even with EnableHexNumpad

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, unicode, input, typing

I'm trying to enter unicode characters by using `Alt+####` but I'm not being able to.

In Registry Editor, I added a new String value called `EnableHexNumpad` with value of 1 in `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method` and rebooted, but nothing has changed. What's happening?

I'm using Window 8.1, tried on Word, Notepad, Chrome, Visual Studio, nothing...

Any clue?
Thanks in advance!

edit:

```
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method"
```

output:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method
Show Status        REG_SZ    1
EnableHexNumpad    REG_SZ    1

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method\Hot Keys
```

Edit: It was PEBKAC!
I was trying to type stuff like Alt+2075 (✅) without actually typing plus!
Thanks to @JosefZ for clarifying this out for me.

Comment: With this registry settings: what happens if you type e.g. **+03b1** while **holding** the **Alt** key? _Greek Small Letter Alpha_ **α** (note that leading `+` is important while leading zeroes are not. So **Alt** + **+3b1** is the same as  **Alt** + **+03b1**

Comment: What the... I feel so dumb, I didn't know I needed to actually type **+**, I thought plus was meaning that I needed to hold alt and type only what comes after the plus symbol! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Rond I was today years old when I found I had to actually press the + and it didn't mean "as well". For the past 25 years of my software engineering career I've been copy and pasting anything which wasn't ASCII like a n00b ☹️

Comment: In almost all other documentation I've ever seen, the "+" _does_ mean hold down a modifier key while pressing some other key(s) so this point needs to be made really clear.

Note also that we're talking about _hexadecimal_ representation of Unicode code points here, e.g. `Alt +117` for ė (U+0117) whereas alt codes were historically decimal.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To improve discoverability, I'm going to copy [JosefZ's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1204586/cant-enter-unicode-character-with-alt-even-with-enablehexnumpad#comment1755360_1204586) from more than a year ago into an answer:

> With this registry settings: what happens if you type e.g. `+03b1` while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key? Greek Small Letter Alpha α (note that leading <kbd>+</kbd> is important while leading zeroes are not. So <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+3b1</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+03b1</kbd>

The registry setting in question is

> HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method

which can be obtained from the command line by typing:

```
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method"
```