# Unicode ALT codes not working for escape character

Tags: windows, windows-registry, unicode, hexadecimal, numpad

I want to be able to type the unicode character  (Escape character) using the windows ALT+001B method. I have created the registry key `EnableHexNumpad` in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method`. I have set it to `REG_SZ` and the value is 1. It works fine for typing codes such as U+006B (lowercase k) however I cannot type control characters such as U+001B. How can I enable this so I don't have to copy and paste it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't enter unicode character with Alt+ even with EnableHexNumpad](https://superuser.com/questions/1204586/cant-enter-unicode-character-with-alt-even-with-enablehexnumpad)

Comment: Not a dupe. Proposed dupe was user error, this is 'windows simply won't do that'.

Answer (score 0):

Alt codes are not unicode, they're 'special' & unique to Windows.

Unicode Escape U+001B is not the same as alt+001B.
I was always of the impression that you enter alt codes in decimal not hex, but if you can get 'k' to work then it would appear it will accept either.
It is probably not completely coincidental that lower case k, U+006B is actually 107 decimal - k is actually supposed to be alt+107 - but you can't rely on that to always be true as alt codes do not cover all unicode, they're a very small subset.
alt+27 [decimal of U+001B] is actually left arrow ←

This is escape `` - though it's invisible here, of course… as it's a non-printing character.
I have no idea how you would do this from alt codes, or even if it exists as an alt code [I couldn't find it in [lists online]](https://www.alt-codes.net).

Actually… that **was** escape. As soon as I saved the answer it vanished & left only the two surrounding quotes ``

Comment: I noticed that too. I originally had the escape character in the question preview, but it seems to have disappeared